# Add array to Value

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

After a `$single_array = array_reduce ($new_array, 'array_merge_recursive', array ());`

I get this result

```
array (size=9)
  'key1' => string 'value1' 
  'key2' => string 'value2' 
  'key3' => string 'value3' 
  'key7' => 
    array 
      0 => string 'value7'
      1 => string 'value13' 
  'key8' => 
    array 
      0 => string 'value8' 
      1 => string 'value14'
  'key9' => 
    array 
      0 => string 'value9' 
      1 => string 'value15' 
  'key19' => string 'value19' 
  'key20' => string 'value20' 
  'key21' => string 'value21'
```

but i would like that

```
array 
  'key1' =>
    array 
      0 => string 'value1' 
  'key2' =>
    array 
      0 => string 'value2' 
  'key3' =>
    array 
      0 => string 'value3' 
  'key7' => 
    array 
      0 => string 'value7' 
      1 => string 'value13' 
  'key8' => 
    array 
      0 => string 'value8' 
      1 => string 'value14' 
  'key9' => 
    array 
      0 => string 'value9' 
      1 => string 'value15' 
  'key19' =>
    array 
      0 => string 'value19' 
  'key20' =>
    array 
      0 => string 'value20'
  'key21' =>
    array 
      0 => string 'value21'
```

It's probably very simple, but I've been blocking for a few hours.

In short, I would like my array_merge_recursive not to add a key only to the same values, but to add an array[0] also to those which were not the same.

EDIT

The code at the start, the goal being to simplify it and knowing that the values generated as well as the order of the structure can be random.

```
<?php
$array = array(
    'sensors' => array(
        '0' => array(
            'data' => array(
                '0' => array(
                    'key1' => 'value1',
                    'key2' => 'value2',
                    'key3' => 'value3',
                )
            )
        ),
        '1' => array(
            'data' => array(
                '0' => array(
                    'key7' => 'value7',
                    'key8' => 'value8',
                    'key9' => 'value9',
                )
            )
        ),

        '2' => array(
            'data' => array(
                '0' => array(
                    'key7' => 'value13',
                    'key8' => 'value14',
                    'key9' => 'value15',
                )
            )
        ),
        '3' => array(
            'data' => array(
                '0' => array(
                    'key19' => 'value19',
                    'key20' => 'value20',
                    'key21' => 'value21',
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
$new_array = array();
foreach ($array as $element1) {
    foreach ($element1 as $j => $element2) {
        foreach ($element2 as $element3) {
            foreach ($element3 as $element4) {
                $new_array[$j] = $element4;
                $single_array = array_reduce($new_array, 'array_merge_recursive', array());
               
            }
        }
    }
}
var_dump($single_array);
```

Comment: Could you please add a [mre]?

Comment: Simple question: Does `array_merge_recursive()` (according to its docs) suggest it should do what you want it to? If not, you'll simply have to write your own algorithm, which shouldn't be that difficult. I'd suggest using test-driven development (TDD) for that, it makes it easier to go from simple to complex cases without breaking things.

Comment: The result of array_merge_recursive is what I want. In fact, I shouldn't have talked about it, it adds confusion to my question. . My question is how then to re-transform the resulting array to add a 0 key to those that don't have one. Easier to work on afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`array_walk_recursive`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) on the original array:

```
$result = [];
array_walk_recursive($array, function ($value, $key) use (&$result) {
    $result[$key][] = $value;
});
```

After running this on the example array you provided, `$result` will be:

```
[
  'key1' => ['value1'],
  'key2' => ['value2'],
  'key3' => ['value3'],
  'key7' => ['value7', 'value13'],
  'key8' => ['value8', 'value14'],
  'key9' => ['value9', 'value15'],
  'key19' => ['value19'],
  'key20' => ['value20'],
  'key21' => ['value21']
];
```

Comment: Thank you, even simpler than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I found, I was just confusing in_array and is_array. My bad

```
$array2 = array();
foreach ($single_array as $key1 => $value1) {
     if (is_array($value1)) {
         foreach($value1 as $key2 => $value2) {
             $array2[$key1][$key2] = $value2;
         }
     }
     else {
         $array2[$key1][] = $value1;
     }
}

var_dump($array2);
```